# RSpec and testing Rails Gem

Tags: testing, rspec2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to set a testing framework for a rails engine. 
I have everything working, I generated the corresponding rspec file with:

```
rails g rspec:install
```

However everytime I want to add a rspec testing file with:

```
rails g integration_test blah
```

The RSpec doesn't take over and instead the standard unit testing framework of rails creates the corresponding files. Any thoughts on where the problem might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved that problem running rails g with --integration-tools option

```
rails g integration_test blah --integration-tools=rspec
```

I do not know how to set rspec as default tool.

Answer (score 1):

I always add in my application.rb :

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework :rspec
end
```

That allows RSpec to replace Rails generator for tests.

Comment: This generates rspec controller specs with `rails g controller` but doesn't seem to affect `rails g integration_test`, at least with rails 3.1.1 (haven't tested earlier versions). The `--integration-tools=rspec` flag doesn't seem to have any effect either.

Comment: try `rails g integration_test blah --integration-tool=rspec` it's `tool` not `tools`

Answer (score 1):

you should put in application.rb:

```
    config.generators do |g|
      g.integration_tool :rspec
      g.test_framework :rspec
    end
```

source: [rails configuration guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html)